# Which Doctor was it that likes Jelly Babies?

Tags: doctor-who

I've been wondering about this for a while since on the 11th doctor's episode he mentioned something about jelly babies.

Answer (score 21):

### The Second Doctor started the trend.

He ate Jelly Babies in [*The Dominators*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dominators), the first time they were seen on screen. He was seen with them in [*The Three Doctors*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Three_Doctors) and [*The Five Doctors*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Five_Doctors_%28TV_story%29), too.

### Three liked them too, apparently.

It's not strictly canon, but the audio adventure [*Ghost in the Machine*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Machine_%28audio_story%29) has Jo Grant find them in his pockets.

### The Fourth Doctor used them as a running gag.

He's the most famous for them because the writers had him tossing the candies around all the time... sometimes literally throwing them.

This is the *specific* reference, based on the voice Smith is doing, in the episode where he channels the previous Doctors.

### The Fifth Doctor...

...used them for barter in an [audio adventure](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Roof_of_the_World_%28audio_story%29).

### Six...

...had them in his pocket during [*The Mysterious Planet*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mysterious_Planet).

### Seven liked them too.

In [the TV Movie](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_%28TV_story%29) he ate them and carried them in his pocket.

### Eight used them in the same film...

...he extolled their virtues as a method of distracting a police officer.

### And Ten seems to have been trying to kick the habit.

Based on [audio](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Forever_Trap_%28audio_story%29) and [prose](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Code_of_the_Krillitanes) stories, he was trying to resist his age-old fondness for them.

Comment: *Face of Evil* is probably the best Jelly Baby exchange

Comment: I always thought the 4th Doctor was the most famous for jelly babies.

Answer (score 4):

**The Twelfth Doctor**
offers them in a cigarette-like container in the episode, "[Mummy on the Orient Express](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Mummy_on_the_Orient_Express_(TV_story))."